# Single jQuery autocomplete for multiple textboxes with different parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

Is there a way I can use this `autocomplete` for multiple textbox elements. The struggle I am facing is that I want to dynamically change the element binding and the source based on the textbox which is calling the function.

```
$("#element").autocomplete({
    source: "../ajax/autocompletes/trucks.php",
    minLength: 0,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#element_id").val(ui.item.id);
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
            this.value = "";
            alert('PLEASE SELECT AN ITEM FROM DROPDOWN!');
        }
    }
}).dblclick(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("search");
});
```

I have searched google but haven't found much.

Comment: Make a function and pass id and source as a parameters, then call it !!!

Comment: Oopps..!!!!! Very silly me!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know , if you need further assitance

```
function multiAutocomplete(element,sourceUrl){
        $(element).autocomplete({
        source: sourceUrl,
        minLength: 0,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#element_id").val(ui.item.id);
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
                    if (!ui.item) {
                        this.value = "";
                        alert('PLEASE SELECT AN ITEM FROM DROPDOWN!');
                    }
                }
            }).dblclick(function () {
                $(this).autocomplete("search");
            });

    }
```

Call like this:

```
    multiAutocomplete('#element','../ajax/autocompletes/trucks.php');
    multiAutocomplete('#element2','../ajax/autocompletes/trucks2.php');
    multiAutocomplete('#element3','../ajax/autocompletes/trucks3.php');
```